# IE8 positions DIV overlay wrong way and keeps playing video when it's hidden

Tags: jquery, flash, video, positioning, internet-explorer-8

Please take a look at: http://www.binarymark.com/Products/PasswordGenerator/default.aspx (the Overview tab, on the diagram). The issue is wjen you click on any of the diagram elements say "Character Groups" all browsers, except IE8 behave well - that is they display the overlay, start playing a video, and when the overlay is closed, the video stops playing an the div is hidden.
IE8, on the other hand has two flaws: it positions the overlay way towards the bottom and too much to the right, and even more annoyingly - it keeps playing video in the background even when the overlay div is closed!
I use flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/ for overlay.
Can you help please?
Thanks.

Comment: oops just fixed the positioning issue by moving the divs higher in DOM, but the playback after div is hidden still remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a confirmed issue in IE (google it and you'll see plenty of complaints).  [This post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806032/flash-video-still-playing-on-div-that-is-removed-using-jquery-ie-bug) recommends some combination of removing and re-adding or cloning and re-adding the objects each time you show/hide the tabs.

An alternative approach, since it seems like you are solely using embedded YouTube videos, is to use the [YouTube JavaScript Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html) and stop the videos each time a tab is shown and/or hidden.

**Updated to include example:**

After digging into the YouTube JS API, I would recommend going with the former solution.  There are two many cross-browser bugs if you don't load each video using SWFObject, which will end up being more work than you're probably willing to spend.  I was able to get a cross browser solution working without SWFObject for a single video, but it won't translate easily into your current setup:

```
<p><a id="showhide" href="#show">show/hide with YT API pause</a></p>

<div id="tab">
    <object id="video1" width="640" height="385" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sUO4bnWtlnE&hl=en_US&fs=1&enablejsapi=1"></param>
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
        <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sUO4bnWtlnE&hl=en_US&fs=1&enablejsapi=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always"  width="640" height="385"></embed>
    </object>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var tab = $('#tab'),
            video1 = $('#video1')[0];
        $('#showhide').click(function (evt) {
            if (video1.pauseVideo) video1.pauseVideo();
            tab.toggle();
            return false;
        });
    })();
</script>
```

On jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZnXY/).

Comment: Can the later be accomplished more easily with jQuery?

Comment: You can certainly use jQuery to retrieve references to the videos which may simplify matters, but you'll still have to use the provided API methods to pause the videos.